# is there a UIImageView in UIWebView.?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiimage

I'm trying to make a simple epub reader, using **UiWebweb**.
First page in epub file always be the cover, a html contains  img label.
But, 
1. How can i detect whether a loaded html contains img?
2. is there a **UIImageView** in **UiWebView.subviews?**
 
any help is appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no `UIImageViews`, `UIWebView` manage itself the rendering of html page, so if an `img` is an `href` into the html page you have to parsing the html file to intercept your favourite tags.

Comment: OK, if i parsing the img label with UIImageView in the  html text from uiwebview, what will happed to the shown Image when i add the UIImageView into UiWebview

Comment: If your question is: can i add a UIImageView as subview of the MKMapView? Yes you can..if not, please explain what you're trying to do.